# Concat same video multiple times failed

Tags: ffmpeg

i am trying to concatenate the same video multiple times and it fails.

This is the command i used: 
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[concatv][concata] -map [concatv] -map [concata] output.mp4

The command fails and the error i am getting is:

Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[concatv][concata] matches no streams.

i expect that i will get the same video 3 times, one after one.
Can someone help?

Comment: Check that `1.mp4` has audio. You should always include the complete log from the ffmpeg command when asking questions. It will help us provide answers and you will get answers much faster.

Comment: You can just use `ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i 1.mp4 -c copy out.mp4`

Comment: Thanks Gyan, it is working, also, llogan, you were right, the audio was corrupted.